# Javascript: Prevent limitations on ajax requests on localhost? Just get XHR "pending"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apache, google-chrome

**Firstly, let me clarify that these requests are coming from and to my localhost on osx.**

The calling, and receiving scripts are both on localhost under the same domain in my hosts.

After a few requests, my XHR requests just show as pending. Interestingly though ones to external sources like Facebook/Soundcloud continue to work...

Here you can see the point at which they start pending:

[image]

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

ps. This is not for consumer facing / production code, this is a one-time script that *i will run once myself* to parse some APIs into my db...

Comment: So how are you making the calls. Showing code would help...

Comment: Don't think it has anything to do with ajax, I think it has to do with localhost not responding. Something going on with your web server or PHP install.

Comment: seeing as the other local calls take so long, i side with TJ that the problem lies outside of JS.

Comment: Well queuing calls could help fix this issue instead of hammering and clogging the "tubes" :) Probably hitting some max limit somewhere and it just locked up.